# Множественное открытие UIViewControllers в IOS

Tags: ios, swift

Привет! У меня следующий case, есть по типу события (данные от пользователей), текущий пользователь может открыть более детально данное событие. В нем могут участвовать другие пользователи и текущий пользователь может перейти на профиль каждого из пользователей. В профиле пользователя содержатся события ( которые он создал) и текущий пользователь может в них так же перейти. Проблема состоит в том, что если это делать много раз (например 15 переходов) то приложение потребляет уже 214 мегабайт (iPhone 7), и если так делать, то я думаю приложение может упасть. Утечек памяти в приложение нету, так как я проверял инструментами и если нажать на tab ( корневой контроллер является наследником от `UITabBarController`), то память приходит в нормальное состояние ( практически как при запуске приложения). Мне интересно, как лучше всего реализовать данную систему (например как это делают в Twitter, там можно из новостной ленты одного пользователя переходить в новостную ленту другого пользователя и так далее). Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо уменьшить потребление памяти каждым новым ViewController'ом настолько, насколько это возможно. Не стоит ограничивать пользователя в количестве открытых друг за другом экранов - так не делает даже Apple (пример - Apple Music).

Если пользователь 500 раз перейдет по экранам не возвращаясь назад, то у приложения кончится память и оно упадёт, и это **нормально** - если пользователь захотел сломать, то ему это удастся.

Можно, однако, минимизировать шанс падения от недостатка памяти, если освобождать неиспользуемые ресурсы в невидимых ViewController'ах:

- Переопределить didReceiveMemoryWarning (освободить легко пересоздаваемые ресурсы, например, объекты CoreData, картинки и т.д.)
- Переопределить viewWillAppear (для создания ресурсов) и viewWillDisappear (для их освобождения)

Если так сделать, то положить приложение смогут лишь желающие весь день сидет и пушить ViewController'ы.

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666589/how-can-i-manage-the-potential-endless-pushing-of-view-controllers-onto-the-navi)